# Generate variable with missing values if condition doesn't hold true

Tags: r

I want to generate a new variable in a data frame which contains the difference of the current row and a lag-value of another variable. However, I want to assign only values for those rows, where a specific condition holds true for a second variable. In this example the new lag-difference variable should only have values for rows with the fruit "Banana". All other rows shall be empty or rather contain NA.

```
 fruitnumbers <- data.frame(numbers=c(2,4,1,5,3,5,2,5,1,3),
                                fruits=c("Apple","Banana","Orange","Cherry","Strawberry","Banana","Banana",
                                          "Apple","Cherry","Banana"))
```

I tried to solve this problem with an if condition:

```
     fruitnumbers$newvar <- if(fruitnumbers$fruits=="Banana"){
      fruitnumbers$numbers-lag(fruitnumbers$numbers, 1)  
    }
```

However, I've received the following warning massage.

```
Warning message:
In if (fruits == "Banana") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

From research, I assume that it has something to do with the fact R wants to check the If-condition for the whole data frame instead of row by row for each value but I'm not quite sure. I'd be grateful for any solution here.

Comment: `if(condition) true.work else false.work` is not vectorised. It would only use the first element of vector to check the condition and ignore rest of elements. You should use `ifelse(condition, true, false)` which is vectorised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `fruitnumbers$fruits` is a vector so when you run `if (fruitnumbers$fruits == "Banana")` only the first element of `fruitnumbers$fruits` is tested(here `"Apple" == "Banana"`).

If you want a vectorized test use the `case_when` function of the library `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
fruitnumbers$newvar <- case_when(
  fruitnumbers$fruits  == "Banana" ~ fruitnumbers$numbers-lag(fruitnumbers$numbers, 1),
  TRUE ~ NA_real_
)
```

Which gives

```
fruitnumbers$newvar
 [1] NA  2 NA NA NA  2 -3 NA NA  2
```

EDIT : as mentioned by someone you could have used the `ifelse` function

```
fruitnumbers$newvar <- ifelse(fruitnumbers$fruits  == "Banana", fruitnumbers$numbers-lag(fruitnumbers$numbers, 1), NA)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do that in two stages:

Create a new column in the data frame:

```
fruitnumbers$newvar <- NA
```

Change the values only for bananas:

```
fruitnumbers$newvar[fruitnumbers$fruits=="Banana"] <- 
  fruitnumbers$numbers[fruitnumbers$fruits=="Banana"] - lag(fruitnumbers$numbers[fruitnumbers$fruits=="Banana"], 1)
```

I am not sure about the lag function in this context. It only returns zeros. Another problem might be hiding there.

Answer (score 0):

In base R, you could try this:

```r
fruitnumbers <- data.frame(numbers=c(2,4,1,5,3,5,2,5,1,3),
                           fruits=c("Apple","Banana","Orange","Cherry","Strawberry","Banana","Banana",
                                    "Apple","Cherry","Banana"))

indexes = which(fruitnumbers$fruits == "Banana")
fruitnumbers[indexes, 'newvar'] = fruitnumbers[indexes, 'numbers'] - lag(fruitnumbers[indexes, 'numbers'], 1)
```

Rest of the row values in column `newvar` would show as blank.